# How to check if $x^TCx\geq0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I have the next 3x3 block matrix C, where each block is a square matrix.

$$
C = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & A & B \\
0 & A+K_1 & B \\
0 & A & B+K_2
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $K_i$ is also a squared diagonal matrix (I have freedom choosing their elements). I want to be sure that $x^TCx \geq 0$ choosing the appropriated $K_i$.

EDIT

The answer is no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless $A=B=0$, this is an impossible mission.

Let $x^\top =(u^\top ,v^\top ,w^\top )$, where the partitioning of $x$ conforms to the partitioning of $C$. If $x^\top Cx\ge0$ for all $x$, then in particular, this is true for $w=0$, i.e. $x^\top Cx=u^\top Av + v^\top (A+K_1)v\ge0$. However, if $A\ne0$, then for every $v\notin\ker(A)$, we can always find a vector $u$ (e.g. $u=-kAv$ for a large positive $k$) such that $u^\top Av$ and in turn $x^\top Cx$ are as negative as possible.

Put it another way, $x^\top Cx\ge0$ for all $x$ if and only if $P=C+C^\top $ is positive semidefinite. For a positive semidefinite matrix $P$, if it has a zero on its diagonal, the row and column containing this zero diagonal entry must also be zero, otherwise $P$ will contain a $2\times2$ submatrix that has negative determinant. Now the $(1,1)$-th subblock of $C+C^\top $ is zero, but the $(1,2)$-th and $(1,3)$-th subblocks are $A$ and $B$. So, $C+C^\top $ cannot be positive semidefinite when $A\ne0$ or $B\ne0$.

Comment: mmmmm, ok, then it is not positive semidefinite for all $u$. But fixing K1 and K2, can we define an open ball $\mathcal{B}$ about $0$? such that $C+C^T \geq 0$ for every $u \in \mathcal{B}$, and $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @noether No. If $x^\top(C+C^\top)x<0$, so is $(\epsilon x)^\top(C+C^\top)(\epsilon x)$. Therefore, if $x^\top(C+C^\top)x$ is negative for $x^\top=x_0^\top=((-kAv)^\top, v^\top, 0)$, it is also negative on the open line segment joining $x_0$ to the origin.

Comment: @noether The definiteness of a matrix $M$ is an intrinsic property. It does not depend on the norm of the vector $x$ in $x^\top Mx$. That's why you can check whether a matrix $M$ is positive definite by investigating its leading principal minors, without calculating the value of $x^\top Mx$ for any particular $x$.

Comment: mmm, I was looking for $x^TCx>0$, not $C+C^T$ being positive definite. You have actually showed it. $C+C^T$ could be positive semi-definite, but $x^TCx > 0$ could be possible for some restrictions on $x$ (an some conditions on $C$).

Comment: @noether I thought you wanted to find $K_1,K_2$ such that $x^TCx\ge0$ for *every* $x$. This is equivalent to the condition that $C+C^T$ is positive semidefinite. If $x$ can be chosen at will, i.e. if you want to find $x, K_1,K_2$ such that $x^TCx\ge0$, this is *always* possible.

Answer (score 0):

$$
C = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & A & B \\
0 & A+K_1 & B \\
0 & A & B+K_2
\end{bmatrix},
$$

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix.

Subtract $1$st row from $(n+1)$ th row then from By a matrix multiplying the matrix $P_1$ from left of $C$(Let $C_1=PC$).

Now we will do the same thing but now we will subtact $2$ nd row from $n+2$ th row by multiplying with the matrix $P_2$.In this way we will go on i.e we will subtract the $i$ th row from $(n+i)$th row using the matrix $P_i$.So we have $P_nP_{n-1}\dots P_{1}C=C_n=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & A & B \\
0 & K_1 &0 \\
0 & A & B+K_2
\end{bmatrix}$

Now again,

Subtract $1$st row from $(2n+1)$ th row then from By a matrix multiplying the matrix $Q_1$ from left of $C$(Let $C_{n+1}=PC_1$).

Now we will do the same thing but now we will subtact $2$ nd row from $2n+2$ th row by multiplying with the matrix $Q_2$.In this way we will go on i.e we will subtract the $i$ th row from $(2n+i)$th row using the matrix $Q_i$.So we have $Q_nQ_{n-1}\dots Q_{1}P_nP_{n-1}\dots P_{1}C=C_{2n}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & A & B \\
0 & K_1 &0 \\
0 & 0 & K_2
\end{bmatrix}$

Now Let $D=Q_nQ_{n-1}\dots Q_{1}P_nP_{n-1}\dots P_{1}$

Here $C_{2n}$ is triangular ,so $C_{2n}D^t=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & A & B \\
0 & K_1 &0\\
0 & 0 & K_2
\end{bmatrix}$ is also triangular(Use the fact that multiplying $C_{i-1}$ by $P_i^t$ from right which will subtract the ist column from the $n+i$ column of $C_{i-1}$.And so for $Q_i$)

So we have $DCD^t=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & A & B \\
0 & K_1 &0\\
0 & 0 & K_2
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: mmm correct me if I am wrong. But your final $DCD^T$ is not symmetric. We know that it has non-negative eigenvalues, but this implies $x^TDCD^Tx \geq 0$ ? Note that $C$ is not symmetric, we should look at $C+C^T$ I guess.

Comment: $0$ is a $n\times n $ matrix?????

Comment: Yes you are right @noether $DCD^T$ is not symmetric. I also dont think that $C+C^T$ can be made positive definite by by manipulating $K_i$. I will give it a thought  and comeback to you if i get it.

Comment: Definite positive I know it is not possible. But definite semi-positive I guess it is not possible neither. Also in the definition I stated that C is composed by 3x3 block matrices, so yes, 0 is a square matrix. I guess for concluding that the eigenvalues are non-negative your answer is right.